# How to use .htcaccess to rewrite non base URLs to another domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite any URL that has a non empty REQUEST_URI to another domain while preserving the REQUEST_URI. The idea being that only www.example.com exists on this domain and any other request should go to www.example2.com.

I've verified that www.example.com has '/' as its REQUEST_URI.

e.g.

```
www.example.com -> should not be rewritten
www.example.com/test.php -> should be rewritten to www.example2.com/test.php
www.example.com/test2.php?id=123 -> should be rewritten to www.example2.com/test2.php?id=123
```

[updated]
I've tried to compare the REQUEST_URI to '/' but that redirects everything:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.example2.com/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I've tried to check if the file or directory exists then redirect it but that is redirecting even the base page (www.example.com)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example2.com/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I've tried to check if there's content after the slash but that redirects nothing:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.+/(.+)$ http://www.example2.com/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Can anyone come up with a working solution to this? It seems like it should be very simple yet I can't seem to get it working.

Thanks.

**Solution:**

FYI: The solution I ended up going with was:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example2.com/$1 [R,L,QSA]
```

The reason being is that if I have any images on www.example.com, they would be rewritten to www.example2.com. The [R] is what made the base URL redirect issue work properly. Credit to poncha for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.example2.com/$1 [R,L,QSA]
```

Without the `!`, your `RewriteCond` is a positive match, not negative.
Also, added `R` flag to force apache send a redirect to browser

Comment: Sorry I wrote it wrong --I actually have your response but that doesn't work.

Comment: Actually it's the R that you added that fixes it!

Answer (score 2):

I think you first try is almost good, you just need to negate the rewrite condition like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.example2.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: Sorry I wrote it wrong --I actually have your response but that doesn't work.

Comment: yeah the missing was the R flag ... I forgot it